# Set height and scroll

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using foundations reveal modal.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 columns image-container">
        <img src="/img/myimage.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="small-8 columns text-container">
        <!-- Long Text Goes Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way (using CSS) to set the height of the modal so it never exceeds the height of the image, and then if the long text exceeds the height, make it scroll?

Comment: set the same height property on both, then set `overflow-y: scroll` on the text-container. If you don't know the size of the image beforehand, this will be tough with just css, you might need javascript to calculate the height and set it on the text container

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h9L05kLt/  heres a fiddle, if you know the height and width already

Comment: It's foundation so it's responsive, I do not know the height

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle/jsbin with several examples showing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Height and overflow in css, By which You can easily control image height

```css
.image-container{
  
  height:300px /*You can place how much height you want to set*/
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.image-container img{
  
  height:auto;
  max-height:300px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 columns image-container">
        <img src="/img/myimage.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="small-8 columns text-container">
        <!-- Long Text Goes Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This may help you

Comment: I am not telling you fix the height of image, But you have to restrict upto a certain height. As you asked it. and its aspect ratio would not be affect.

Comment: By-d-way i am trying to helping you but u gave me -ve points, Its not fare. if you don't like my answer just comment and ignore it, But don't give negative points

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got what you need. Please take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/an1gsdm0/

I wrapped the whole row in a *table-row*. The image and the text being an *table-cells* in it. The text's table-cell has *inline-block* div  with text inside. You can test it by manipulating the .image class size. Then the text field height will adjust. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id='first' class='img-div'>
        <img class="image" src='http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2141/web_design_creatives/128/small_smile.png'/>
    </div>

    <div class="outer-text">
        <div id='second' class='text-div'>Put a long text here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    display: table-row;
}

.img-div {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
}

.outer-text{
    display: table-cell;

    height: 100%;
    width: 190px;
}

.text-div{
    display: inline-block;

    height: 100%;

    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

To test it for custom various image sizes change the height of the image:

```
.image{
    height: 190px;
}
```